# search method in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hello  i want  to do a search in my database using dropdownlist

this is it :

```
     @Html.DropDownList("Id", new List<SelectListItem>{
      new SelectListItem {Text="Agent name",Value="1"},
       new SelectListItem {Text="Location",Value= "2",}
         }, "choose",new { @class = "dropdown" })

       <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
```

my   contoller  :

```
  public ActionResult Index(int Id=1)
    {

        var agentlocation = new AgentLocationViewModel();

            if (Id == 2)
                agentlocation.agents = db.Agents.OrderBy(a =>a 
                   .Location.LocationName).ToList();
            else
            {
                agentlocation.agents = db.Agents.ToList();
            }


        return View(agentlocation);
    }
```

when  the  user  will choose  location the data will be ordered by location

the  Problem is   when  i  try  to  click  on   search button  nothing  is  happend  (it's  like   the  value  is  null  )

Comment: even  if  i  want  to add  a  httppost  method    nothing  happend

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add form element. Without form element, nothing will be submited.

```
<form action="/Home/Index" method="get">
  @Html.DropDownList("Id", new List<SelectListItem>{
  new SelectListItem {Text="Agent name",Value="1"},
   new SelectListItem {Text="Location",Value= "2",}
     }, "choose",new { @class = "dropdown" })

   <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Or using Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Id", new List<SelectListItem>
    {
    new SelectListItem {Text="Agent name",Value="1"},
    new SelectListItem {Text="Location",Value= "2",}
    }, "choose", new { @class = "dropdown" })

    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Comment: wow!!!   i  forget  to  add............@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

think  you  my  freind